# Laravel Query Builder - where(1=1) getting error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, query-builder

I am trying to build this PHP MySQL query to Laravel Query builder:

```
$sql = "SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_position, employee_city, employee_extension, DATE_FORMAT(employee_joining_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as employee_joining_date, employee_age ";
$sql .= " FROM employee WHERE 1=1";
if (!empty($EmployeeNameSeach) ) {
    $sql .=" AND  employee_name LIKE '".$EmployeeNameSeach."%' ";    
}
if (!empty($SalarySeach)) {
    $sql .= " AND  employee_salary LIKE '".$SalarySeach."%' ";
}
if (!empty($PositionNameSeach) ) {
    $sql .= " AND  employee_position LIKE '".$PositionNameSeach."%' ";
}
if (!empty($CitySeach) ) {
    $sql .= " AND  employee_city LIKE '".$CitySeach."%' ";
}
if (!empty($ExtensionSeach) ) {
    $sql .= " AND  employee_extension LIKE '".$ExtensionSeach."%' ";
}
if (!empty($JoiningDataSeach) ) {
    $sql .= " AND  employee_joining_date LIKE '".$JoiningDataSeach."%' ";
}
if (!empty($AgeSeach) ) {
    $sql .= " AND  employee_age LIKE '".$AgeSeach."%' ";
}
```

And what I am doing is -

```
    $baseQuery  =   DB::table('employee')->select('employee_name', 'employee_salary', 'employee_position', 'employee_city', 'employee_extension',"employee_joining_date", 'employee_age', 'employee_id');
                        //->select('name as user_name', 'email')

    //Applying Filters
    $query  =   $baseQuery->where(1, '=', 1);
    if(!empty($EmployeeNameSeach))
        $query  =   $query->orWhere('employee_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$EmployeeNameSeach.'%');
    if(!empty($SalarySeach))
        $query  =   $query->orWhere('employee_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$SalarySeach.'%');
    if(!empty($PositionNameSeach))
        $query  =   $query->orWhere('employee_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$PositionNameSeach.'%');
    if(!empty($CitySeach))
        $query  =   $query->orWhere('employee_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$CitySeach.'%');
    if(!empty($ExtensionSeach))
        $query  =   $query->orWhere('employee_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$ExtensionSeach.'%');
    if(!empty($JoiningDataSeach))
        $query  =   $query->orWhere('employee_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$JoiningDataSeach.'%');
    if(!empty($AgeSeach))
        $query  =   $query->orWhere('employee_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$AgeSeach.'%');

    //Ordering and Limiting Current data
     $query =   $query->orderBy($columns[$column_index_for_ordering], $column_ordering_direction)
                ->skip($start_data_index)->take($per_page_content_number);
     $data          =   $query->get();
```

So I am getting error for-

```
    $query  =   $baseQuery->where(1, '=', 1);
```

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the `WHERE 1 = 1` part. No need at all.

Also, as pointed out in the comment below, you want to use `where`, not `orWhere`.

---

Here's your code, considerably cleaned up:

```php
$query = DB::table('employee')->select('employee_name', 'employee_salary', 'employee_position', 'employee_city', 'employee_extension', "employee_joining_date", 'employee_age', 'employee_id');

$filters = ['EmployeeNameSeach', 'SalarySeach', 'PositionNameSeach', 'CitySeach', 'ExtensionSeach', 'JoiningDataSeach', 'AgeSeach'];

foreach ($filters as $filter) {
    if (empty($$filter)) continue;

    $query->where('employee_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$$filter.'%');
}

$query->orderBy($columns[$column_index_for_ordering], $column_ordering_direction)
      ->skip($start_data_index)
      ->take($per_page_content_number);

$data = $query->get();
```

The code above uses`$$filter` as a [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to loop through the filters. I don't know where those filters some from, but you should probably have them in an associative array instead. Would make life easier.

Comment: I believe he does not need to use `orWhere` as well as it's an `or` statement.  Question has all `and`s in the query.

Comment: @user3158900 - Either case, there's no need for `WHERE 1 = 1`.

Comment: The `where` condition should use `$$filter` as well :).

Answer (score 8):

You haven't posted the error, but I'm guessing you're getting:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'

That's because the first parameter of the `where` method is expected to be a column name and will get quoted. So in your case when you have:

```
$query = $baseQuery->where('1', '=', '1')
```

the SQL generated would be:

```
WHERE `1` = 1
```

So you should be using `whereRaw` to avoid any quoting:

```
$query = $baseQuery->whereRaw('1 = 1');
```